# Rally Standard Report, Issue with APIKey,but works when logged in

Tags: rally, code-rally

I've created an iteration burn-down chart in the code below. When we try to launch this from a web server with the apikey appended we see a window generated with the Rally Login screen not the graph. If you are already logged into the Rally tool, the graph does generate correctly.  We only see this issue with the standard report as code generated using treegrid does work as expected when the APIKey is appended to the path.

Thanks!
Mark

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>iterationburndown</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.create("Ext.Container", {
                context: {},
                items: [{
                    xtype: "rallystandardreport",
                    width: 750,
                    height: 500,
                    reportConfig: {
                        report: "IterationBurndown",
                        iteration: "April",
                        subchart: "hide",
                        title: "Iteration Burndown"
                    },
                    project: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/51186097359",
                    projectScopeUp: !1,
                    projectScopeDown: !0
                }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
            });

       Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: "iterationburndown",
            parentRepos: ""
        });

    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a limitation with those old style charts rendered by the Standard Report component.  The A1 service those use does not support API Keys.

The best you'll be able to do would be to re-implement the chart using the [Rally.ui.chart.Chart](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.chart.Chart) component and the Lookback API.

Some resources:

- https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/lookback_api
- https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/data_visualization

There's also a related app already implemented for a release burndown you could use as a place to get started: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Is there a way to generate the older key type? When I tried that (that was our original plan), that tool never provided a key when we provided all of the correct information. Thanks! Mark

Comment: Are you talking about login key?  That was only compatible with the 1.x version of appsdk and is considered insecure and deprecated at this point...

Comment: Is there a different way to do this that allows me to use the apikey? I guess something other than standardreport?  Thanks! Mark

Comment: I added some more info to the answer above ^^.  Hope that helps...  Writing charts is probably the most challenging thing to do as far as apps go.